# Cómo obtener un array a partir del contenido del mismo array en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

estoy utilizando una API de google que me devuelve resultados en arrays que nunca tienen el mismo orden, por ejemplo el array es

```
console.log(r.properties);
```

y tiene como resultado

```
0: {long_name: '13', short_name: '13', types: Array(1)}
1: {long_name: '5', short_name: '5', types: Array(3)}
2: {long_name: '8-chōme', short_name: '8-chōme', types: Array(3)}
3: {long_name: 'Ginza', short_name: 'Ginza', types: Array(3)}
4: {long_name: 'Chuo City', short_name: 'Chuo City', types: Array(2)}
5: {long_name: 'Tokyo', short_name: 'Tokyo', types: Array(2)}
6: {long_name: 'Japón', short_name: 'JP', types: Array(2)}
7: {long_name: '104-0061', short_name: '104-0061', types: Array(1)}
```

en este caso, el que me interesa es el array con el nombre de la ciudad (Tokyo), que vendría siendo el array con la key 5, sin embargo, no es una posición fija, podría estar en cualquier otra posición

el array que me interesa[5] tiene otro array dentro de su contenido, llamado types

```
types: Array(2)
0: "administrative_area_level_1"
1: "political"
```

el valor de la key[0] es el que quiero obtener para asegurarme de que el array seleccionado sea el correcto (tokyo), el valor de ese array es `administrative_area_level_1` ya que con esto puedo asegurarme que el "nivel" de la dirección es la prefectura y no otra cosa

cómo puedo obtener el array "padre" si su contenido en "types" es `administrative_area_level_1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo filtrando el array por la propiedad `types`:

```js
const result = [
  {
    long_name: '13',
    short_name: '13',
    types: [
      'administrative_area_level_2',
      'political'
    ],
  },
  {
    long_name: '5',
    short_name: '5',
    types: [
      'political',
      'administrative_area_level_1',
    ],
  },
  {
    long_name: 'Tokyo',
    short_name: 'Tokyo',
    types: [
      'administrative_area_level_1',
      'political',
    ],
  },
];

const validEntries = result.filter((entry) => entry.types[0] === 'administrative_area_level_1');
```

Comment: aquí tienes un pequeño bug, si el array types viniese "administrative_area_level_1" en la posición 1, ya no te funcionaría, lo ideal es buscar en el array completo y dejar el código escalable por si algún día Google decide cambiar de posiciones esos elementos o incluso decide agregar otro mas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Existen metodos para arrays en javascript. Estos reciben varios argumentos, uno de ellos indica el elemento propio de la lista, con el cual podras conseguir el objeto. Primero: iteras en cada elemento de r.properties; luego te aseguras que la ciudad es igual a "Tokyo". De ahi retornas las ciudades que tengan el primer index de "types" que sean "administrative_area_level_1".

```
let cities = [];
r.properties.forEach((element) =>{

if (element[long_name] === "Tokyo" && 
        element[types][0] === "administrative_area_level_1"){
       cities.push(element)
    }
})
```

Y ahora en cities vas a tener el objeto con ciudad de tokyo, y "administrative_area_level_1"

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con lo siguiente, primero filtro la lista por el valor que tenga "administrative_area_level_1" de la siguiente manera:

```
var results = a.filter(function(i){
   return i.types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_1') >-1;
});
```

y para acceder al valor long_name asociado al de Tokio puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
var city;
if(results.length){
   city = results[0].long_name;
}
```